# Integration testing of a CAS secured web service

Tags: testing, spring-security, integration-testing, cas

I have a web service that accepts CAS proxy tickets over HTTP Basic authentication headers via Spring Security. How do I perform integration testing with my client since there seems to be no programmatic way to fetch CAS tickets?

Since the CAS setup is one of the more tricky aspects of the project configuration I really need that to be part of our automated integration tests but I have hit a roadblock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You be interested in the CAS RESTful API: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/RESTful+API

The RESTful API follows the same basic protocol as the original CAS2 protocol, augmented with some additional well-defined resource urls. This is particularly helpful for applications that need to programmatically access CAS.

Hope this helps.